# How to plot two different sets of scatter points against number of months and calculate regression line?

Tags: microsoft-excel, regression

Say I have the following table:

| **Month** | **X** |
| --- | --- |
| April 2015 | 2 |
| May 2015 | 6 |
| June 2015 | 16 |
| July 2015 |  |
| August 2015 |  |

I also have another table:

| **Month** | **Y** |
| --- | --- |
| April 2015 | 19 |
| May 2015 | 20 |
| June 2015 | 18 |
| July 2015 |  |
| August 2015 |  |

X and Y aren't ordered pairs. They're two different sets of scatter points.

You can see that X and Y values are missing for the months of July and August of 2015.

How can I have LibreOffice Calc/Microsoft Excel graph X against the months, then Y against the months, and find a line of best fit between these two sets of scatter points so that not only can future values be extrapolated, but I can know *in what month* the extrapolated values will be?

Also bonus question: with a table like this, is there any reason to entertain a logarithmic regression, or is linear more than enough?

Comment: Models based on 3 points? Brave!

Comment: @DMM It helps to read the Code of Conduct from time to time, and remember that what is easy to you may be very hard for someone else ;) https://superuser.com/conduct

Comment: Y is basically a horisontal line, whereas X could be linear or exponential. Two ways to approach this. Plot seperately and add trendlines (tick show formula on chart). Then use the formulae to extrapolate half way between both. Alternatively merge the two data sets, sort by date, then plot as one, add trendline and compare.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of initial points worth noting.

1. Excel provides a Forecast Sheet option (in the Forecast group of the Data menu on the ribbon) and this uses a moderately sophisticated approach (based on exponential smoothing) for predicting future values of a time series. Whilst it can certainly be used by anybody with access to Excel, it is probably as well to have some appreciation of what is going on "under the hood" before using it on real world problems.
2. Although Excel will add what it calls a "trendline" to some charts, determining the value of the trendline at any point requires either doing it "by eye" from the chart itself or, providing the correct trendline display option is chosen, copying the numeric values of the trendline equation displayed on the chart and using these in Excel formulae to calculate the values of the trendline at a specific point.

Instead of adopting either of these approaches, the approach below explicitly fits a model using Excel formulae and then uses the co-efficients of this model to calculate the values estimated by the model.

There appear to be two tasks involved in the original question: (i) model fitting and estimation of values and (ii) charting the data, the model and its estimated values. These are dealt with separately below.

**Model fitting and estimation**

Statistical models such as  linear regression models are, of course, fitted to numerical data so the labels "April 2015", "May 2015", ... , "August 2015" need to be converted to numerical values.

Whilst it might seem obvious that 1,2,3, 4 and 5 can be used, this requires some knowledge about what the data represent. An alternative to 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 might be, for example, the total number of days after the first Wednesday in 2015 to the fourth Wednesday in each of the 5 months. This would instead yield values of 112, 140, 168, 196 and 231 in place of the monthly labels.

For simplicity, I will stick with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Also, for simplicity, I will, for the moment, stick with a simple linear model. Further, because Excel`s prompts and statistical modelling terminology both use "x" and "y" and give specific meanings to these, I will change the "X" and "Y" of the question and substitute "P" and "Q" instead.

A simple linear model has the mathematical form of

*y = a + b×x*

where *x* is the independent variable (in this case the numbers associated with the months), *y* is the dependent variable (the numbers associated with either **P** or **Q**) and *a* and *b* are the co-efficients of the model. In linear regression, the values of the co-efficients are estimated using a particular mathematical approach (the method of least squares). In Excel, this is implemented using the functions `INTERCEPT` and `SLOPE` and, respectively, these functions estimate the values of *a* and *b*.

Each function takes two arguments, the first is a cell range containing the known *x* values and and the second is a cell range containing the known *y*'s. So for example, if the numbers corresponding to months April 2015, May 2015 and June 2015 are contained in `A2:A4` and the corresponding **P** values are in `C2:C4` then

*a* is calculated using the formula `=INTERCEPT(A2:A4,C2:C4)` and
*b* is calculated using the formula `=SLOPE(A2:A4,C2:C4)`

The values estimated by the model can then be calculated from the co-efficients using the simple "formula"

`=a+b*month`

So, once *a* and *b* have been determined, the estimated values for **P** (denoted by **Pest**) can be calculated for July 2015 and August 2015 by, in this simple example, substituting the values of 4 and 5 for `month` in the above formula. Repeating the exercise allows model co-efficients and estimates to be calculated for **Q**.

The screenshot below shows the above implemented in Excel.

[image: Screen shot -simple linear regression models]

**Charting**

Generally, the appropriate chart type to use for a linear regression model with one independent variable is a simple scatter chart.

Although Excel allows data to be selected prior to creating such a chart, Excel's "guesses" as to which bits of the data are the independent variable (*x* values) and which are dependent variables (*y* values) are not always brilliant, particularly for a chart which has 4 series on it (**P**, **Q**, **Pest** and **Qest**) which all use the same independent variable (the month values).

The easiest way to proceed is to create a complete blank chart by selecting an empty area of worksheet prior to using the Insert command from the menu (choose "Insert Scatter (X,Y) or Bubble Chart" from the Charts group and from the dropdown options choose "Scatter with Start Lines and Markers"). This should open the "Select Data Source" dialog as shown next.

[image: Select data source dialog]

Clicking the "Add" button will allow each series to be added through the "Edit Series" dialog

For the first series, **P** the data is added as shown (based on the screenshot above)

[image: Edit series dialog]

Once the first series has been added, the series for **Q**, **Pest** and **Qest** can be similarly added.

Some editting of the format of each series and other elements of the chart can then be performed to get a chart which might look like that shown below.

[image: Chart showing actual and estimated values for series P and Q]

Excel does not allow the month labels to be inserted onto this chart - for a scatter chart the Edit option in the right hand side of the Select Data Source dialog is greyed out, preventing changes being made to the "Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels".

However, because equal intervals have been used for the *x* values (1, 2, 3, 4 and 5) the chart type can be changed to "Line". This will not distort the shape of the lines on the chart and will now allow the range `B2:B6` to be used to label the x-axis. Be warned, though, changing a chart type like this can cause some of the carefully applied formatting such as colours and markers of the data series to be lost.

**An exponential model**

Rather than using a simple linear model for the model fitted **P**, an exponential growth model might be used instead. This has general form

*y = a×exp(b×x)*

Taking natural logs of both sides yields

*ln(y) = ln(a) + b×x*

which is a linear model with *ln(y)* rather than *y* as the dependent variable.

The techniques set out above for a simple linear model can now be used to estimate the co-efficients of this linearised model. This is left as an exercise but to 6 places of decimals, these co-efficients are

*ln(a)* = -0.326943 (Intercept)
*b* = 1.039721 (Slope)

*a* can be determined by applying the `EXP` function to the Intercept value and this yields (again to 6 places of decimals)

*a* = 0.721125

Applying these new values of *a* and *b* to the equation of the exponential model (*y = a×exp(b×x)*) with the *x* values of 1, 2, 3,4 and 5) yields estimates of P for this new model of

2.039649 (April 2015)
5.768998 (May 2015)
16.317191 (June 2015)
46.151986 (July 2015)
130.537530 (August 2015)

These and the previous estimates from the linear model provide a graph which looks like:

[image: Linear vs Exponential estimates for series P]

**Discussion**

Clearly in July and August the two models are producing very different estimates of the values of **P**. In July the exponential growth model estimate is twice that of the linear model and in August it is five times higher.

On the face of it, comparison of actual and estimated values for the three months April, May and June shows that the exponential model is a better fit to the data than the linear model. The error sum of squares (ESS) value (the sum of the squared differences between the actual and estimated values over the 3 months) is 6 for the linear model and just 0.156 for the exponential model. (In terms of assessing how well different models fit the data, lower ESS values generally indicate better fit.)

However, without a lot of additional information (such as a deep understanding of the physical processes giving rise to the **P** data), it really is guesswork as to which model is most appropriate. In the absence of that additional information, 3 data points are simply not enough to make a sound judgement as to whether the underlying process is linear, exponential or one of many other possibilities. In such circumstances, building a predictive model on the basis of just 3 data points is not something to be recommended, not least because the wide variation in predicted values may well be associated with risks of choosing the wrong model.

For example, if the data represents, say, sales, then choosing the wrong model might have severe consequences in terms of inventory, staffing and other capacity costs (erroneously choosing exponential) or loss of sales, profit and business reputation (erroneously choosing linear).